# How to Set dynamic array value in TCL?

Tags: tcl

If there is a list, and the list item will be got from other file. I want to set every list item as an array, i do this:

```
set lista [element1 element2 element3 ...]
foreach item $lista {
    array set $item {1 a 2 b 3 c}
}
```

if I want to add key-value:

```
set test elment1
array set $test {4 d}
```

I wonder is there any other better structure to set these dynamic array? Thanks!

Comment: What is the actual problem? Your example will work in some cases and not work in others, but we need to know what problems you experience to be able to advise you on what is "better" (better is always relative). Note that a Tcl array is a structure of (local) *names*, not a structure of values. If you need a structure of values, a `dict` might be closer to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Using a [`dict`](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/dict.htm) will provide you the flexible data structure you're looking for:

```
set lista [list elem1 elem2 elem3]
set initial_map {1 a 2 b 3 c}

set d [dict create]
foreach elem $lista {
    dict set d $elem $initial_map
}
puts $d
# => elem1 {1 a 2 b 3 c} elem2 {1 a 2 b 3 c} elem3 {1 a 2 b 3 c}

puts [dict get $d elem2 2]
# => b

# add a new key-value to "elem3"
dict set d elem3 4 d
puts $d
# => elem1 {1 a 2 b 3 c} elem2 {1 a 2 b 3 c} elem3 {1 a 2 b 3 c 4 d}

# manipulate the "sub-dictionaries"
puts [dict keys [dict get $d elem3]]
# => 1 2 3 4
```